# How to set apache user to access GitHub

Tags: apache, github, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up [apache-git-sync-tool](https://github.com/Perennials/apache-git-sync-tool) to deploy from GitHub to a shared webserver, but the first step is:

> 1. Setup your apache user to access github.

How is this done? I’m at a loss for how to do this. The documentation for apache-git-sync-tool goes in to more detail:

> Let say the apache user is 'www-data' ('__www' on MAC). You need to
>   add his ssh public key to github. If you don't have generated key you
>   need to do it with following command: sudo -Hu www-data ssh-keygen -t
>   rsa Thus will generate id_rsa key for www-data user normally in
>   /var/www/.ssh/ . You will see the location in the output. Leave
>   passphrase blank. For successful generation /var/www/ must be with
>   write access for www-data user.

I’ve tried a few variations on that while SSHing into the Apache server, but had no luck. Here’s what  happened:

```
[myusername@webhosting-login01 ~]$ sudo -Hu www-data ssh -T git@github.com
sudo: unknown user: www-data
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

[myusername@webhosting-login01 ~]$ sudo -Hu myusername ssh -T git@github.com
Sorry, user myusername is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/ssh -T git@github.com' as myusername on webhosting-login01.mycompanydomain.com.

[myusername@webhosting-login01 ~]$ sudo -Hu __www ssh -T git@github.com
sudo: unknown user: __www
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

[myusername@webhosting-login01 ~]$ sudo -Hu __www ssh -T git@github.mycompanydomain.com
sudo: unknown user: __www
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I’m not sure if maybe I was supposed to do this somewhere else? Or is the Enterprise version of Github different

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is to SSH into Apache *as the Apache user which will be running the script* and then [follow this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

So if you have access, you should do it with `__www` or `www-data`. In my case, the user is actually the hostname (which is a subdomain of the organization).